# Add custom icon to orders' list view in Prestashop

Tags: button, prestashop, orders

I would like to add new button to order's list view, but I have no idea how to do it:

[image: what I would like to do]

I want to do it in way that new upgrade will not delete it.

Edit: This new button will just open new browser window so it's completely independent of PrestaShop functionalities. But I would like to put it in this toolbar line.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Currently your question is too broad. Please explain the purpose of this button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with overrides. Create a file called `AdminOrdersController.php` in your `overrides/controllers/admin/` folder, and add the following:

```
<?php
class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    public function initPageHeaderToolbar()
    {
        parent::initPageHeaderToolbar(); // this will assign native icons

        // This is where you add you custom icon
        $this->page_header_toolbar_btn['my_custom_icon'] = array(
            'href' => self::$currentIndex.'&mycustomaction&token='.$this->token,
            'desc' => $this->l('My custom action', null, null, false),
            'icon' => 'process-icon-save'
        );
    }

    public function initProcess()
    {
        parent::initProcess();

        if (Tools::getIsset('mycustomaction')) {
            if ($this->tabAccess['view'] === '1') {
                $this->display = 'mycustomaction';
                $this->action = 'mycustomaction';
            }
            else
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You do not have permission to edit this.');
        }
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        if ($this->display == 'mycustomaction')
            $this->content.= $this->renderMyCustomAction();
    }

    public function renderMyCustomAction()
    {
        // this is where you render your custom page.
    }
}
```

Note that this is a quick mock up. It should work, though :)

**UPDATE**

If you just want the icon to open a new page, leave only the `initPageHeaderToolbar` method and provide the right `href` attribute, you can delete the `initProcess`, `initContent` and `renderMyCustomAction` methods. I'll leave them in my original reply in case someone else finds it useful.